# Can a finite ring have a characteristic $0$?

Tags: ring-theory, positive-characteristic

I am working on studying Abstract Algebra and doing one of the review problems for the exam.  I do not think a finite ring can have characteristic zero because when I think of, for example, Integers mod $4$, this ring has a characteristic greater than $0$. I also remember learning about infinite rings and I almost naturally associate an infinite ring with having a characteristic of $0$.  Could anyone help me prove the above statement? I am thinking of starting off with a contradiction: let R be a finite ring with characteristic $0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... then $z\cdot 1\neq 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. That is, having characteristic $0$ means that nonzero integer multiples of $1$ are always nonzero.

Then $\{z\cdot 1\mid z\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\}$ must be finite, since it's a subset of your finite set.

Then $z\cdot 1 = z'\cdot 1$ for $z,z'$ two distinct nonzero integers.

Reorganizing that you get $(z-z')\cdot 1=0$. But $z-z'$ is a nonzero integer, so this contradicts what we said before that nonzero integer multiples of $1$ are always nonzero.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether your ring has unity, so here is a general argument.

If a ring $R$ has characteristic zero, then, for each $n>0$, there is some $a\in R$ with additive order $>n$.  This means the set $\{0,a,2a,\ldots ,na\}$ consists of distinct elements (this requires the existence of additive inverses), so that $|R|>n$.

Since $n$ was arbitrary, $R$ is infinite.

This argument is a little simpler if we can assume that $R$ has unity.  In that case, $R$ must actually contain $\mathbb{Z}$ as an additive subgroup.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To have characteristic $0$ means that for no finite sum $1 +1 + \cdots +1$ do you ever get a repeat.  So, they're all different, so the ring must be infinite.

To be clear, though, an infinite ring MAY have positive characteristic.  Take $R = \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, e.g.

Comment: _Technically_, characteristic $0$ just means that you never get a $0$ in any of those finite sums, not that you never get a repeat. It's pretty easy to prove that getting $0$ and getting repeats at all are equivalent, but I felt like it should be pointed out.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the characteristic of a ring $R$ as being the natural number $n$ such that $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}\cong (1),$$ where $(1)$ denotes de subring generated by the multiplicative identity, which is sometimes called the *prime ring* of $R$, then you can easily see that a ring of characteristic $0$ has to be infinite, for it contains an infinite subring.

*Edit:* this applies only if your ring has a multiplicative identity, if it doesn't, then the answer given by Slade is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

No it can't be zero because the characteristic of a finite ring, say (R,+,.), divides the order of (R,+). It's a trivial proof.